# How to control depth resolution of Kinect v2 on ofxMultiKinectV2?

Tags: macos, kinect, openframeworks

I am working openFrameworks using [ofxMultiKinectV2](https://github.com/hanasaan/ofxMultiKinectV2) to control Kinect v2 on Mac.
Wondering how to control depth resolution of Kinect v2.

Would be good to share with me any tips about it.
I have to do uneven face tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framerate and resolution cannot be controlled manually in Kinect v2. There is no such function for that yet.

In addition, framerate is highly dependent of the room illuminance (15 if it's too dark, 30 otherwise). Good question nevertheless... :)